# react-native: memory increase when loading images in flatlist

Tags: react-native

I'm using [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) to display images in a flatlist in my react native app. Image dimensions are 512 x 512, with about 500kB for each image as size. Images are downloaded from the server and are placed in the flatlist.

I'm testing this with the Allocations instrument of xCode.

When opening the app, I hit about 20mb. But once the images (only 10 images) are loaded, it shoots up to +250mb.

[image]

It's weird because those 10 images does not have 250mb in total combined size.

My flatlist looks like this (simplified):

```
const Component = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <FastImage source={{ uri: item.uri }} style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth }} />
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'serverURL'
    }).then(({data: { images }}) => {
      setImages(images);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={images}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.imageId.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Component item={item} index={index} />}
      initialNumToRender={10}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
      windowSize={11}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good chance it has to do with this prop:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Component item={item} index={index} />}
```

Extract that into a (non-inline) function to better optimize your renders. Right now, React is creating a function reference for every list item on every render.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you help me with a (simple) snippet (or link) to how I should change this to a non-inline function?

Comment: Sure. Something like `const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => <Component item={item} index={index} />` and then use it as `renderItem={renderItem}`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out!